# Unable to reinstall On premises data gateway for Azure, since I am trying to resolve the No instance issue

Tags: azure-logic-apps

> It looks like you are trying to reinstall. Please uninstall the current version first.

No matter what I do:

1. deleted the On-premises data gateway folder from C:/ProgramFiles/On Premise Data Gateway.
2. Removed the registry entry to delete the service (though it still won't go even after restarting the system)
3. Checked the logs at 
   C:\Users\PBIEgwService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\On-premises data gateway

I am unable to be successful with the reinstall. Can someone please help me with uninstalling the On premise gateway?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with this program, but installed programs on Windows are also saved in the Package Cache (**C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{GUID}**), and if there is a corresponding msi Windows thinks the program is installed.

Removing this folder (make sure you delete the correct one!) will enable windows to ask you if the entry should be removed from installed programs once you click uninstall again.

After this you should be able to install it again.